# Xamarin - Is there a property in CareouselView (and other views) similar to the CachingStrategy property of ListView?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The ListView in Xamarin has a property named [CachingStrategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listviewcachingstrategy?view=xamarin-forms). My question is, is there a similar property for other views, in my specific case a CarouselView? Or can I somehow achieve the same behavior?

Comment: I search some info, but I can not find any way to achieve the same effect like ListView CachingStrategy.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Thank you for sharing your time. Seeing your profile I think you know well about Xamarin. I've asked another question about Xamarin, perhaps you will be interested in it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/65106771/13738662